# How to create instances of a html page and dynamically load into a list of the main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have main html page and then I need to add a dynamically created list of a template of another html file I created.

Basically I have a template for one item of the list in a separate HTML page.

So what I need to do is create instances of that html page, populate the correct data, and then add it to list of items on the main html page.
I would know how to do this in java but I am not sure how to do this in HTML / Javasript.

What is the preferred way to dynamically create html object instances.

Thanks

Comment: To get the complete instance of the page in DOM using jquery, you can use "*" selector like $("*"); Now if you console.log($("*")); you will se complete html reference. Here you can modify your html and use it. If i understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the html template with jQuery load method

```
  $("#container").load('path/template.html', function(){
    // some code to populate your template      
  });
```

Note: this will only work through a web server, not locally as you will hit the browsers cross site origin policy. use apache or similar

Comment: How do I keep creating new instances of that template? That looks like it will load just that html page and I can modify. How do I create another one with different values? Also I would like to try to avoid any cross site issues, so is there a better way to try to do this?

Comment: just wrap it in a jquery.each loop http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ 
so for each instance load the template.

The cross origin stuff is only if you are doing it on your local machine, once on a server its fine. Its baked into browsers.

To be honest this is the only i know to do this without either a front end framwork (angular etc) or a backend (PHP, Ruby, C# etc).

Comment: I do have to do it on my local machine but we are using node.js

Comment: Ok, you can do it on your machine, you just need to load your web page through a webserver rather thant just opening it in a browser. apache can do this, its free and simple to use. Try something like xampp https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: Or if you are on windows, just run it through IIS